# How to let the method of 'map' work in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, axios

I would like you to give me a magic bullet so that my code could work.

```
<script.js>
const getVocas = async () =>{
    const allWords = axios.get("http://localhost:3000/")
    .then(() => {
        let vocas = Object.entries(allWords);
        
        let { data } = vocas;
Here is an error below for "data.map"
        vocas = data.map((word) => {
        const { title, content } = word;
        
        return `
        <div class="single-thread">
          <h3>${title}</h3>
          <p>${content}</p>
        </div>
      `
    })
})};
getVocas();
```

I got to know that the map method can be applied to an array only, and I used this code "Object.entries(allWords)", but it did not work showing the error:
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map').

In addition to a script.js file, here is a server.js file:

```
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Words = require('./models/WordTable')
const app = express();
app.use(express.static("public"));
app.use(express.json());

app.listen(3000, console.log("動く"));



mongoose.connect("mongodb+srv://

<these are my id and password>

@cluster0.ourgdrv.mongodb.net/WordTable?retryWrites=true&w=majority"
).then(()=>console.log("success"))
.catch ((err)=>console.log("error"));

// API発信部分
app.get("/words", async(req, res)=>{
    try{
        const allWords = await Words.find({});
        res.status(200).json(allWords);
    }catch(err){
        console.log("error1")
    }
});
```

Comment: `Object.entries` returns an array which you then try to destructure with *object* destructuring which isn't going to work: arrays do not have a "vocas" property. It's not clear what you're trying to do here.

Comment: Thank you so much for your quickest comment.  I try to get data from Mongo DB by a function of 'getVocas' and put them  into HTML elements. I am extremely grateful to you if you could kindly tell me how to work the map method (vocas = data.map).

Answer (score 1):

`Object.entries` returns an array of two-element arrays, therefore:

```js
let data = Object.entries(allWords);
let vocas = data.map((word) => {
  const [title, content] = word;
  ...
});
```

Comment: I could manage to solve this problem, thank you.